# How to enable internet connection if router stops working

Tags: router

I have a Cyberoam UTM and a Static ip address provided to me by my ISP.

Now what I can do if my firewall or my UTM gets damaged or stops working. What hardware or resources I need in case my utm stops working?

The connection is like

ISP internet cable - - > UTM - - > Local Network.

Is there anyway I can connect my local network to the internet in case if my utm stops working. Thanks.

Comment: Not a real answer, but what you are searcing for is called "redundancy". I am unfamilliar with Cyberroam, so try looking in the documentation if your device supports any kind of redundant setup.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The google search indicates the UTM appears to be a firewall. While you could get say a cheap router/firewall put it on a shelf and if the UTM dies physially replace it, that seems a bad idea as that boxes are not functionally equivlant. This is a form of redundancy though a static kind, as mentioned in the comment. Net of this is that if you need the firewall function you need a duplicate physical box. MAYBE you can 'limp along' with a less expensive spare box while you wait for your replacement firewall but that is a business call. Lastly most people here will tell you that your ISP connection will fail far more often than your hardware and that is what you need to make redundant first.

Comment: I don't need firewall functionality just a working internet if my firewall fails in any case?

Comment: Yes you DO need firewall capability.  You should buy spare hardware if you think you need it, but honestly, as @fredpbaker points out, it is much more likely your ISP is going to fail before your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You need a device that supports Port Address Translation (PAT), Dynamic Host Control Protocol (DHCP), and basic routing.  Your best bet is to get a consumer grade 'router' and test it one night and then have it on hand for if the primary device fails.

BTW, a windows server can do this too, but, realistically, just go buy a $50 router.